# Cannot use tf.stack to merge a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am a beginner of Tensoflow and python. Right now I have two function **get_lines()** and **generate_rays()** which intend to generate a tensor. I write these functions in numpy and it works well, but when I shift it to Tensorflow, i.e. change horizon_lines to Tensor and change np.vstack() to tf.stack(), it raise a error.

The code:

```py
def get_lines(lines, angle):
    res = tf.round(lines / tf.tan(angle))

    return lines, res

def generate_rays(horizon_lines,
                        angles={0: np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])}):
    temp = [[get_lines(horizon_lines, a)] for a in angles[0]]
    rays_left = tf.stack(temp, axis = 0)
```

where **horizon_lines** is a Tensor.

But it shows:

```
  File "/home/zchen/PycharmProjects/test/tools/../lib/layer_utils/generate_rays.py", line 64, in generate_rays
    rays_left = tf.stack(pp, axis = 0)
  File "/home/zchen/.conda/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zchen/.conda/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 998, in stack
    value_shape = ops.convert_to_tensor(values[0], name=name)._shape_tuple()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: If I read it correctly [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py) from array_ops.py it has to do with the structure of your provided data (read: array).

Comment: I think you have a typo, shouldn't `temp = [get_lines(horizon_lines, a)] for a in angles[0]` be `temp = [get_lines(horizon_lines, a) for a in angles[0]]`?

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, thank you! I corrected it. I mean in my original code I add a square bracket between them, so it will not raise a error.

Comment: @ZF007 so you means my structure is wrong, i.e., I need to change **horizon_lines** to other things?

Comment: I reackon jdehesa has it right about the typo... side effect of that is the incorrect dataset/array. You can check that at args_ops.py if you include a line at 997 where you print the dataset provided to see what happens (include sys.stdout.flush() to force a printout). When done/fixed remove that code or disable it.

Comment: @ZF007 Thanks! I mean it already have a square bracket between the loop in my code, it just my typo when I post my code to Stackoverflow. I.e., the error was raise under the code **temp = [[get_lines(horizon_lines, a)] for a in angles[0]]**